# What's the best way to search a text file for consecutive repetitions and return the text with highest number of them?

Tags: python-3.x, list, group-by, duplicates, slice

I'm extremely new to programming in general and have only been learning Python for 1 week.

For a class, I have to analyze a text DNA sequence, something like this:
CTAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATGACTA

for these specific keys: AGAT,AATG,TATC

I have to keep track of the largest number of consecutive repetitions for each, disregarding all but the highest number of repetitions.

I've been pouring over previous stackoverflow answers and I saw groupby() suggested as a way to do this. I'm not exactly sure how to use groupby for my specific implementation needs though.

It seems like I will have to read the text sequence from a file into a list. Can I import what is essentially a text string into a list? Do I have to separate all of the characters by commas? Will groupby work on a string?

It also looks like groupby would give me the highest incident of consecutive repetitions, but in the form of a list. How would I get the highest result from that list out of that list to them be stored somewhere else, without me the programmer having to look at the result? Will groupby return the highest number of consecutive repeats first in the list? Or will it be placed in order of when it occured in the list?

Is there a function I can use to isolate and return the sequence with the highest repetition incidence, so that I can compare that with the dictionary file I've been provided with?

Frankly, I really could use some help breaking down the groupby function in general.

My assignment recommended possibly using a slice to accomplish this, and that seemed somehow more daunting to try, but if that's the way to go, please let me know, and I wouldn't turn down a mudge in the direction on how in the heck to do that.

Thank you in advance for any and all wisdom on this.

Comment: This seems like a Divide and Conquer problem to me, but it's probably not the best approach for beginners. Is this a computer science or bioinformatics course? If it's bioinformatics we have specific tools for these things.

Comment: @RaiyanChowdhury Yes! This is absolutely for a course. I am not in the bio information sector! Haha It's just an exercise. Can you tell me what Divide and Conquer means? I've seen that on other postings but I don't know what that means in programming per say.

Comment: Divide and Conquer means to solve a problem by breaking it up into smaller problems and solving them recursively. Essentially what you want to do is split your sequence in two, and determine the max number of sequences in either half. Then, you check if there are any sequences that cross the middle, and you need to check if it overlaps your 'optimal' sequence. For your base case, when the length is less than or equal to 4, you can easily check if any interest sequence is present.

Comment: In general, I recommend this approach only if you have at least a year of programming experience at it's an intermediate level programming concept.

Comment: Well, I've been taking a class since May. So let's say I have a solid 2 months of trying to program. Are you suggesting I should not try to Divide and Conquer at this stage?

Comment: That's probably too early to try Divide and Conquer, and it's only needed if your interest sequences may overlap. If your interest sequences are guaranteed to be non-overlapping, an iterative approach will work. In this case, just read through the sequence four bases at a time to check for your interest sequence.

Comment: Note, your interest sequences are not guaranteed to be non-overlapping, as the example (AGATATC) demonstrates.

Comment: Also, can you clarify what you mean by consecutive sequences? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a similar solution to the previous post, but may have better readability.

```
# The DNA Sequence
DNA = "CTAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATGACTAGCTAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATGACTAGAGATAGATAGATCTAG"

# All Sequences of Interest
elements = {"AGAT", "AATG", "TATC"}

# Add Elements to A Dictionary
maxSeq = {}
for element in elements:
    maxSeq[element] = 0

# Find Max Sequence for Each Element
for element in elements:

    i = 0
    curCount = 0
    # Ensure DNA Length Not Reached
    while i+4 <= len(DNA):

        # Sequence Not Being Tracked
        if curCount == 0:

            # Sequence Found
            if DNA[i: i + 4] == element:
                curCount = 1
                i += 4

            # Sequence Not Found
            else: i += 1
        
        # Sequence Is Being Tracked
        else:

            # Sequence Found
            if DNA[i: i + 4] == element:
                curCount += 1
                i += 4

            # Sequence Not Found
            else:
                # Check If Previous Max Was Beat
                if curCount > maxSeq[element]:
                    maxSeq[element] = curCount
                
                # Reset Count
                curCount = 0
                i += 1
    
    #Check If Sequence Was Being Tracked At End
    if curCount > maxSeq[element]: maxSeq[element] = curCount

#Display
print(maxSeq)
```

Output:

```
{'AGAT': 5, 'TATC': 0, 'AATG': 0}
```

Comment: Thank you! Okay, one more question if you don't mind: once I have maxSeq, how do i search for that in the dictionary? Can I just say ````if maxSeq == value```` as I iterate through the supplied dict? Should I convert them to int first? I saw somewhere that you could do a ````if dict_row == newdict_row```` type thing but it was saying then if anything was different from the two rows, it wouldn't work, for instance if the original has a name and the new one doesn't then it will automatically go false. I can post a separate question if that's more appropriate.

Comment: No problem! If I understand your question correctly, if maxSeq were the maximum sequence and dict were the dictionary, then you use ```dict[maxSeq]``` to look up maxSeq in the dictionary.

Comment: Note: I'm not referring to the variables in my program.

Comment: Apparently I've misunderstood the assignment and there are sequences that are longer than just four letters. Is there a way to use a slice that is flexible? Can I just repeat this formula and adjust the lengths for the longer sequences? Someone suggested maybe created a list of the lengths and then using array notation lengths [0], lengths[1] etc. to accomplish this but is there a more efficient way?

Comment: There are sequences of 4, 5, and 8 letters. Is there a way to accommodate each without just repeating this whole thing 3 times?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like a groupby problem since you want multiple groups of the same key. It would easier to just scan the list for key counts.

```
# all keys (keys are four chars each)
seq = "CTAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATGACTAGCTAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATGACTAGAGATAGATAGATCTAG"

# split key string into list of keys: ["CTAG","ATAG","ATAG","ATAG", ....]
lst = [seq[i:i+4] for i in (range(0,len(seq),4))]  

lst.append('X')  # the while loop only tallies when next key found, so add fake end key

# these are the keys we care about and want to store the max consecutive counts
dicMax = { 'AGAT':0, 'AATG':0, 'TATC':0, 'ATAG':0 }  #dictionary of keys and max consecutive key count

# the while loop starts at the 2nd entry, so set variables based on first entry
cnt = 1 
key = lst[0] #first key in list
if (key in dicMax): dicMax[key] = 1  #store first key in case it's the max for this key

ctr = 1 # start at second entry in key list (we always compare to previous entry so can't start at 0)
while ctr < len(lst):   #all keys in list
    if (lst[ctr] != lst[ctr-1]):  #if this key is different from previous key in list
        if (key in dicMax and cnt > dicMax[key]):  #if we care about this key and current count is larger than stored count
            dicMax[key] = cnt  #store current count as max count for this key
        #set variables for next key in list
        cnt = 0
        key = lst[ctr]
    ctr += 1  #list counter
    cnt += 1  #counter for current key
    
print(dicMax)  # max consecutive count for each key
```

---

Raiyan Chowdhury suggested that the sequences may overlap, so dividing the base sequence into four character strings may not work. In this case, we need to search for each string individually.
Note that this algorithm is **not** efficient, but readable to a new programmer.

```
seq = "CTAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATGACTAGCTAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATGACTAGAGATAGATAGATCTAG"
dicMax = { 'AGAT':0, 'AATG':0, 'TATC':0, 'ATAG':0 }  #dictionary of keys and max consecutive key count

for key in dicMax: #each key, could divide and conquer here so all keys run at same time
     for ctr in range(1,9999):  #keep adding key to itself ABC > ABCABC > ABCABCABC
         s = key * ctr  #create string by repeating key  "ABC" * 2 = "ABCABC"
         if (s in seq):   # if repeated key found in full sequence
             dicMax[key]=ctr   # set max (repeat) count for this key
         else:
             break; # exit inner for #done with this key
             
print(dicMax)  #max consecutive key counts
```

Comment: Thank you. And this will return the highest incidence of consecutive repetitions of each? I'm sorry, but would you mind walking me through the code a little bit? As I said, I've been trying to learn python for literally a week and there is a lot I haven't seen yet.              I see you're using the slice notation. And then are you creating a new list with the while loop?

Comment: Hey Mike, I considered this but the problem is the sequences can overlap. When they do, we need to find the combination with the highest number of sequences, which is why I suggest Divide and Conquer.

Comment: Okay, I guess I didn't think that they would overlap. Because only one can exist at a time right? AGAT, AATG, and TATC can't exist within each other, I don't think. Am I not understanding what you mean by sequences overlapping?

Comment: By overlapping, I mean that the full sequence may contain several keys depending on how you split the sequence. For sequence "ABCDABCDABCD", there are 3 "ABCD" if split "ABCD" | "ABCD" | "ABCD". There are 2 "CDAB" if split "AB" | "CDAB" | "CDAB" | "CD".

Comment: @ReaganPfifer Unfortunately, they can overlap. Consider the sequence AGATATC. Though this is the only overlap.

Comment: @Mike67 okay, I think I see what you mean. Is that a result because of the slice? Like depending upon where the slice occurs it may happen in the middle of key?

Comment: @Raiyan Chowdhury Yes, that does make sense. So in the second loop posted earlier, it is searching for each key individually versus searching for all 3 at once, and that would fix a potential overlap? Am I understanding that correctly? Does that mean that even though it is searching one by one, it will still return the values of all 3?

Comment: @Mike67 Can I ask why the loop is inefficient?

Comment: @ReaganPfifer The loop is inefficient because it's traversing the string multiple times (1 for each key) which isn't necessary to solve the problem.

Comment: @Raiyan Chowdhury And what it outputs is a dict value right? So when I compare them, I must compare two dictionary values?

Comment: @ReaganPfifer Yes, but do you need the maximum number for each sequence? Or just the sequence with the maximum number?

Comment: @Raiyan Chowdhury: Max number for each sequence. The unique identifier of the 3 diff max sequence numbers will be how I identify to whom it belongs from the supplied dictionary.